# Two map functions within object declaration

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I loop through multiple arrays and "pair" them, when declaring an object? Assuming there are two arrays that contain same amount of data. I would like to map each of them and allocate to objects properties.

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
{
  name: john,
  surname: doe,
  datasets: [{
    data: 1,
    vehicle: car,
    color: red
    },
    {
    data: 2,
    vehicle: car,
    color: blue,
    },
    {
    data: 3,
    vehicle: car,
    color: green
  }]
}
```

this is what I have done:

```
function Constructor (name, surname, data, vehicle, colors) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.data = data;
  this.vehicle = vehicle;
  this.colors = colors;

  this.person = {
    name: name,
    surname: surname,
    datasets: [{
      data: data.map(data => ({
        data,
      vehicle: vehicle,
      color: colors.map(color => ({
        color
      }))
      })),

    }]
    }

};


var testing = new Constructor ('john', 'doe', [1,2,3], 'car', ['red', 'blue', 'green']);

console.log (testing.person);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `data` and `color` always have identical lengths, you can use the `index` in your map function, which is passed as a second argument:

```
data.map((data, i) => ({
    data,
    vehicle: vehicle,
    color: colors[i]
  })
)
```

For non-matching data sets (i.e.: one has more data than the other), there are several approaches you could take.

1. Use a default color (if `data` has more items):

   ```
   data.map((data, i) => ({ 
     // ...
     color: colors[i] || "black"
   })
   ```
2. Throw an error if the data-sets do not align:

   ```
   if (data.length !== colors.length) throw "data length does not match color length";
   ```
3. Take the shortest set of data and discard the extra's

   ```
   Array.from(
     { length: Math.min(data.length, colors.length) },
     (_, i) => ({
       data: data[i], color: colors[i], vehicle
     })
   );
   ```

And, of course, many more!

Comment: @lovemyjob if they don't have identical lengths, you haven't specified what your expected behavior is, and maybe you should think about that

Comment: @lovemyjob Depends on what your expected result is. You could do a check and throw an error if they differ (`if (data.length !=== colors.length) throw "data and colors must have the same length"`), or you could use a default value or end early.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks for the correction. English isn't my first language :)

Comment: @user3297291 thanks. How could I use default value for color if its length is less than data?

Comment: @lovemyjob `colors[i]` -> `colors[i] || defaultValue`

Comment: I was busy answering the comment in an edit to my question, but I see it has already been handled ;) Anyway: I added some strategies to the answer.

Comment: `{ length: Math.min(...[data, colors].map(a => a.length)) }` though I have no idea if that would be considered more or less readable. Let's just call it a different approach :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to propose an alternative solution you may not have thought of. If `colors.length <= data.length` is always `true`, you can consider cycling through the colors using `%` remainder operator like so:

```
data.map((data, i) => ({
  data,
  vehicle: vehicle,
  color: colors[i % colors.length]
})
```

```js
function Constructor(name, surname, data, vehicle, colors) {
  this.name = name;
  this.surname = surname;
  this.data = data;
  this.vehicle = vehicle;
  this.colors = colors;

  this.person = {
    name: name,
    surname: surname,
    datasets: [{
      data: data.map((data, i) => ({
        data,
        vehicle: vehicle,
        color: colors[i % colors.length]
      }))
    }]
  }
}

var testing = new Constructor('john', 'doe', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'car', ['red', 'blue', 'green']);

console.log(testing.person);
```

Which produces the sequence `red, blue, green, red, blue` for `data.length === 5`